# CAST (string as date) | Not Working | AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

After I create my external table and assign 'unformattedDate' as string, I am not able to use function CAST(string as date)

Here is my CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTable
(unformattedDate as string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://...'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Query:

```
Select unformattedDate, SPLIT_PART(unformattedDate,' ',1) as "unformattedDate2"
```

Results:

| unformattedDate | unformattedDate2 |
| --- | --- |
| 9/9/2022 12:00:00 AM | 9/9/2022 |

This is the query that fails when I try to cast as date

```
Select unformattedDate,
SPLIT_PART(unformattedDate,' ',1) as "unformattedDate2",
CAST(SPLIT_PART(unformattedDate,' ',1) as Date) "unformattedDate3"
```

ERROR:

```
SQL Error [100071] [HY000]: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date:  [Execution ID: 80c26833-daac-44e8-8441-3464d9757a6d]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us a few rows of data in the source files, so we can see how the date is stored?

Answer (score 0):

`9/9/2022 12:00:00 AM` is a non-standard date format. If it was in `2022-09-09` format, then Athena would be able to understand it.

You will need to use something like:

```
select date_parse('9/9/2022','%d/%m/%Y') from table
```

However, if it is really only showing one digit for the day and month, even that might be difficult.

See: [Date and Time Functions and Operators — Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)